# How do I add new notification sound programmatically on Android

Tags: android, audio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, programmatically-created

I'm writing an Android App which needs to add new notification sounds programmatically. As far as I can see, Android looks ONLY for notification sounds in the res/raw folder of the app, so my app must place the sounds there. However, the res/raw folder is read-only so how do I do this?

The notification will later be send to the phone from a server using firebase cloud messaging

Any search for a solution was without any luck